# Linear Progress indicator could not manage its state while downloading files

Tags: flutter, dart, state, dio

I am new to Flutter and am currently working on a Flutter app that downloads files from given links. The issue is that when only one link app is working fine but when more than one link arrive file does not download. I receive the link data in json file then I parsed the json and used these links inside the listview.builder. I tried very much but could not find the solution. Here is the code for the screen. Main issue is that I think state is not managed well.

dsharing.json file contain name and links of files

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import '../services/services.dart';

class ReceiveScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const ReceiveScreen({Key? key, }) : super(key: key);

@override
State<ReceiveScreen> createState() => _ReceiveScreenState();
 }

 class _ReceiveScreenState extends State<ReceiveScreen> {

 Map<int, double> progress = {};
 int received = 0;
 int total = 0;
 var _url = "http://192.168.1.100:50500";

 List<Receiver> receivers = [];
 @override
 initState()
 {
   super.initState();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("Receive Files"),
  ) ,
    body: Column(
      children: [

        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: ()async
            {
              await getUrls();
            },
            child: const Text("Get Response")
        ),

        Text(rsponse),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: getUrls(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Files>  snapshot)
                {
                  if(!snapshot.hasData)
                    {
                      return const Center(child:  CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    Files files = snapshot.data!;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: files.names!.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index)
                      {
                        
                        return Column(
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async
                              {
                                final path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/${files.names![index]}";
                                await Dio().download(
                                    files.urls![index],
                                    path,
                                    onReceiveProgress: (received, total)
                                    {
                                      progress[index] = received/total;
                                    }
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text("${files.names![index] } Download")
                          ),
                          LinearProgressIndicator(
                            value: progress[index],
                            minHeight: 20,
                          )
                        ],
                        );
                      }
                  );
                }
        )

     
      ],
    )
);
 }
 String rsponse = "";
 fetchDataApi() async
 {
   var response = await get(Uri.parse("$_url/dsharing.json"));

   if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
     return jsonDecode(response.body);
    }
   }

 Future<Files> getUrls() async
 {
   var data = await fetchDataApi();
    return Files.fromJson(data, _url);
  }



  }



class Files
{
  final List? names;
  final List? urls;

  Files({ this.names, this.urls});

  factory Files.fromJson(Map map, String url)
  {
   var fileNames = [];
   String name = map['name'];
   if(name.contains(":"))
    {
     int index = name.indexOf(":") + 1;
     name = name.substring(index + 1, name.length);
     var x = name.replaceAll(" ", '^*&');
     fileNames = x.split("^*&").toList();
    }
   else
     {
      fileNames.add(name);
     }
     var x = map['data'].toString().split("|dsharing|").toList();
     var fileUrls = x.map((i) => url + "?/q="+ i).toList();
      return Files(
      names: fileNames,
      urls: fileUrls
    );
   }


 }
```

Comment: have you debugged your application to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes I have debug my app and its shows that progress value turned into negative and no change in progress after that.

Comment: Why did it turn to negative?